# вывести в меру в Power Bi значение введенное через input визуала HTML

Tags: javascript, html, powerbi

Просьба подсказать как можно вывести в отдельную меру значение введенное пользователем через тег input используемого в визуале HTML. Код HTML выглядит так:

```
   test1 = 
"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <title>Percent</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
      <form name='test_num' method='post'>
        <p>Укажите число</p><br>
        <p><input type='number' id='num' min='5000' max='500000'></p>
        <button onClick='submit()'>Кнопка</button>
      </form><br>
    </div>
    <script>
  function submit(){
    var a = document.getElementById('num');
    var b = a.value;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне нужно получить значение var b и применять его в dax формулах. Как его получить?
ПС: знаю, что можно использовать параметры, но здесь работает ограничение в 1000 значений, у меня значений гораздо больше, поэтому не подходит.

Comment: Так вы же сейчас получаете значение и ограничений в js на количество нет. Что именно не получается?

Comment: введенное значение в инпут нужно подставить в dax формулу. Например, у меня есть мера - % дисконта (для каждого пользователя свой дисконт), мне нужно в новой мере вывести значение инпута * дисконт по пользователю. Сейчас есть только мера test1(код html) и нет меры с введенным значением